# Monit process 'mysql' Not Monitored

Tags: mysql, linux, ubuntu, monit

Any ideas why monit will not monitor mysql in this setup???
I've gone through everything I can find here to solve the problem to no avail.

These are my versions:

```
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS
Release:    14.04
Codename:   trusty
```

```
mysql --version
Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.5.41, for debian-linux-gnu (x86_64) using readline 6.3
```

```
monit -V
This is Monit version 5.6
```

I've tried both of these setups:

```
check process mysql with pidfile /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
    group database
    start program = "/etc/init.d/mysql start"
    stop program = "/etc/init.d/mysql stop"
    #if failed host 127.0.0.1 port 3306 protocol mysql then restart
    if failed unixsocket /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock protocol MYSQL then restart
```

And get this:

```
monit status
Process 'mysql'
  status                            Not monitored
  monitoring status                 Not monitored
```

Can confirm:

`/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid`

reads the same as

`ps -e | grep "mysql"`

Log:

`/var/log/monit.log`

shows no errors

Monit is running as root:

```
ps -eaf | grep monit
root      4549     1  0 05:18 ?        00:00:00 /usr/bin/monit -c /etc/monit/monitrc
root      5248 12440  0 05:53 pts/0    00:00:00 grep --color=auto monit
```

Comment: Try `monit  monitor all` in command line.

Comment: Or just  `monit monitor mysql`.

Comment: For me the answer at https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/447212/how-do-i-configure-to-monit-monitor-a-process-after-it-restarts helped, i.e. using "then exec $script " instead of using "then restart"   "stop/start" programs.

Answer (score 9):

as already mentioned, this should do:

```
monit monitor mysql
```

sometimes the "timeout" statement can disable monitoring in case of too many restart errors, I do not recommend using statements like this:

```
if X restarts within Y cycles then timeout
```

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like monit might not have access to the user database group.

What does `ps -eaf | grep mysql` read?